# Difference between theme preprocessor & processor function?

Tags: 7, theming

The question is is self-explanatory!

**Another question**, suppose I have a template file named `a-b--c--d.tpl.php`

What would be the preprocessor function for this template file? I suppose `themename_preprocess_a_b__c__d(&$vars)`?

Sorry for my poor knowledge. I'm newbie to drupal & started with drupal 7.

Comment: The question has been asked on stackoverflow
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064876/preprocess-vs-process-functions-in-drupal-template

Comment: Thanks @Onita didn't check SO. Can you please answer the 2nd question I made? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### For the template

If the page is "/my-node", the page template will be "page--my-node.tpl.php".

### For the Prepocess

But you cannot using it "themename_preprocess_my_node(&$vars)" because my-node isn't a hook ! You can find differents hooks with this page http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal and with the search box,  type 'theme_'. You can see the differents hooks for the preprocess